# DLL not found on IIS Remote Server C# WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a C# WCF Web Service on a remote server running on IIS 8.5. One of the method of this web service tries to call a function in another custom DLL on the remote server but it returns a System.Exception specifying that it doesn't found the DLL. I logged the exception on the DLL Loader and it returns the right path to the DLL though.

The DLL is a C++ DLL used to execute a Matlab function via the runtime (installed on the server and referenced in the PATH variable as well as the DLL.
My DLL is situated in the bin folder of the project. I also tried to put it into the %windir%/System32 but same error.

By the way, the web service works great while on my Local Computer. The error only occurs while deployed

Any idea on how I can have my web service to find the DLL and execute the function?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use CFF explorer https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388 to see all the dependencies chains. Maybe your dll is dependent on another dll that is not there.

Comment: Log the exception detailed to know DLL name which not found to ensure your suggestion is true and the program search for DLL that already exists first, it seems the application search for DLL that really isn't exist in production system.

Comment: What DLL troubles you? Database drivers/providers are installed on your server?

Comment: Hi Lucian, all the dependencies are there, thank you for the soft.
Hi Mojtaba Tajik (just edited the post with your information in it), the logs are showing that the right path is used.
Hi nilsK, it is a custom DLL (just edited the post to say so) and all the providers are installed.

Comment: What is the bitness of your C++ dll? What is the application pool bitness on the remote machine? There is no IIS 6.1. Very likely you are using IIS 7.5.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, the C++ dll is 32 bits. The Application Pool has "Activate 32 bits applications" at false.
Yes you're right, it was Windows Server version, my IIS is in 8.5.